# Подключение к БД MySQL

Tags: java

Хочу подключится к БД по нажатию кнопки. в обработчике события добавил класс под названием Class. Но на этом участке кода

```
public class Class{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:127.0.0.1 port 3306/magaz_laguna\",\"root\", \"****\"");
    conn.close();
}
```

выдает ошибку. Подсвечивает все что в фигурных скобках.  Подскажите пожалуйста, может я что то не так ввел или ввел что то лишнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, любые операции в классе должны выполняться в пределах какого-либо метода. Во-вторых, не стоит определять класс с именем `Class`, иначе простое обращение к методу `Class.forName` будет искать данный метод в первую очередь в вашем же классе. Ну и в третьих, строка для подключения не совсем верно написана.

Comment: Так этот класс у меня в методе  `actionPerformed` для кнопки или он не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

В обработчике кнопки Вы должны поместить не класс, а создавать объект этого класса. В самом же классе код подключения поместить в конструктор. И, как было сказано, не называйте класс `Class`.